# Firebase: Upload an image without the user selecting it

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I was wonder to know if it is possible to upload an image to Firebase Storage without the user action of selecting what is the image that he want to upload. Actually my app goes well with an "upload" button in which I select what is the image I want to upload.

But when I try this:

```
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File("com.estrongs.files/storage/emulated/0/TFG/user_information.jpg"));
StorageReference riversRef2 = storageReference.child("tfg/user_information.jpg");

riversRef2.putFile(file)
```

I receive an error message from Firebase saying: "**An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code**...."

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to place a file inside a reference that is wrong

```
StorageReference riversRef2 = storageReference.child("tfg/user_information.jpg");

riversRef2.putFile(file)
```

check that you are trying to add to riversRef2 the photo , and riversRef2 is the reference to a photo.

change your reference and it will work

Also, did you placed your permissions in your app to access external or internal storage ? maybe try to allow permissions manually and check what happens